# Google Cloud Console - Setting up a VM instance from cloning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-console-developer

I currently have a VM Instance in Google Cloud Console. This VM instance has an application that is live which is running against an Apache Server. This application is not in the standard `var/www/html` folder but instead in a folder `var/www/some_folder`.

I would like to make a replica of this application and have it set up as a "staging" server. I started by cloning the VM instance by following these steps:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-similar-instance

However after successfully cloning the VM, when I navigate to the external IP I am just prompted to the default welcome page for Apache Server. How would I configure the VM instance to either redirect to my application when visited or add a domain that points to my application on the apache server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "Create similar" button does not clone the vm, it just clones the configuration.

To create a clone you will need to [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) then [create a new instance from the snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot)

Comment: Thanks. this is what I did. The VM Instance is set up correctly. I am having a hard time trying to navigate to the ip and have it spin up my web app as oppose to the default apache page.

Comment: If you have validated all your files are present on the disk, it could possibly be an Apache configuration issue.

Comment: I found a conf file in the `available-sites` folder. Could I update that manually?

Comment: You could do, some form of configuration management tool would be the preferred way of doing it, but in the absence of that it may help you solve your problem.

Comment: I tried updating it manually and restarting the `httpd` on the machine. it did not point to the web app. I am out of ideas.